# Split data.frame row into multiple rows based on commas

Tags: r, string

I am attempting to split a row in a `data.frame` based on the character sequence ", ". Here's an example:

```
mydat <- data.frame(v1 = c("name, name2", "name3", "name4, name5"),
                v2 = c("1, 2", "3", "4, 5"), 
                v3 = c(1, 2, 3))
```

What I would like to end up with is a `data.frame` like so:

```
 v1   v2   v3
name  1    1
name2  2   1
name3  3   2
name4  4   2
name5  5   3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
out <- concat.split.multiple(mydat, c("v1","v2"), seps=",", "long")


out
     v1 v2 v3
1:  name  1  1
2: name2  2  1
3: name3  3  2
4: name4  4  3
5: name5  5  3
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for directing my attention to that package!

Comment: `concat.split.multiple()` is deprecated. Use `cSplit()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way using `data.table` package and its new `tstrsplit` function

```
library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.5
setDT(mydat)[, lapply(.SD, tstrsplit, ", "), by = v3]
#    v3    v1 v2
# 1:  1  name  1
# 2:  1 name2  2
# 3:  2 name3  3
# 4:  3 name4  4
# 5:  3 name5  5
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, users with an inclination for `tidyverse` packages can use `tidyr`'s `separate_rows` function along with `select` from `dplyr` (to maintain the order of the columns) to get this done:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydat %>% separate_rows(v1,v2,sep=", ") %>% 
        select(v1, v2, v3)

#     v1 v2 v3
#1  name  1  1
#2 name2  2  1
#3 name3  3  2
#4 name4  4  3
#5 name5  5  3
```