# Add new line in df using grep or regex

Tags: r

I have a dataset that goes like this:

```
    Clubs         Player          Goals
    Barcelona       A                1
    Liverpool       B                2
    M United        C                1
    Arsenal         D | E            1
...
```

Problem I am facing is in the rows like 4th row. I am thinking, I have to grep for "|". Followed by creating a new row below:

Desired Result for the 4th row is as below:

```
Arsenal         D             1
Arsenal         E             1
```

I am unable to do a Grep AND add a new line with the data from above line copied below.

Can someone please share how this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: [try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571978/split-value-from-a-data-frame-and-create-additional-row-to-store-its-component) [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525811/how-to-separate-comma-separated-values-in-r-in-a-new-row) [next](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113263/splitting-a-single-column-into-multiple-observation-using-r) [time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758504/split-data-frame-row-into-multiple-rows-based-on-commas)

Comment: Thanks for the link Rawr. I searched long and hard but was focused on getting Grep to work on special chars and 'insert' special chars. I had no clue there was a package that could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to split `|`-concatenated data into separate values. And you also want a [long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data) data shape (not a wide one). One option:

```
df <- read.table(header=T,sep=",",text="  Clubs,Player,Goals
Barcelona,A,1
Arsenal,D | E,1")
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, 2, "|", "long")
#        Clubs Player Goals
# 1: Barcelona      A     1
# 2:   Arsenal      D     1
# 3:   Arsenal      E     1
```

Also see the help file `?cSplit`.